# useLocation: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the `useLocation` hook in my function component but I'm getting `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`.

My app is structured like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    // ...
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                // ...
                <Navigation themes={themes} />
                // ...
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/mytheme">
                        <MyTheme />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

With the `Navigation` component (see above) looking like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Navigation(props) {
    const location = useLocation(); // ---> this is the problem
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.themes.map((theme, index) => {
                    return <Link key={index} to={"/" + theme.id}>
                        { theme.name }
                    </Link>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Navigation works fine, but I want to use `useLocation` in the `Navigation` component to highlight the active "page".

Comment: Do your versions of `react` and `react-dom` match?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, both are `16.12.0`.

Comment: hmm, other than that the other two issues the docs point to don't seem relevant: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: And the error disappears as soon as you remove this line? Maybe there is another hook causing the issue? The way you are using it seems correct.

Comment: I made a pen with basically the same code and I don't see any errors: https://codepen.io/mcmillhj/pen/OJVxPdR?editors=1111. Can you post more of your code? There might be an issue in the surrounding code. Are there any other hooks used?

Comment: Make sure React is not being loaded more than once in the page.

Comment: It seems that the error is gone after restarting my machine and IDE. Not sure what happened and apologies. Just to confirm: yes, the error disappeared when removing the `useLocation()` line. I used `react-scripts start` to run the app.

Comment: Hooks are such a stupid idea. totally ruined React for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of function components that works.
this can also helps to those who are using a class, and don't want to replace the react class component to function component:

**In React-Router-Dom V6**-> the withRouter wrapper class is not exists any more.

See:
[What happened to withRouter? I need it!](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)

> This question usually stems from the fact that you're using React class components, which don't support hooks. In React Router v6, we fully embraced hooks and use them to share all the router's internal state. But that doesn't mean you can't use the router. Assuming you can actually use hooks (you're on React 16.8+), you just need a wrapper.

**Here is my implementation**, a little more easy-to-use than doc example:

**For the op of this question**: you can use the `ComponentWithRouterProp` to see how it should be written:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation, useNavigate, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} {...{location, navigate, params}} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

**Use (when exporting your component):**

```
export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

And, in your component, you can use:

```
this.props.location.pathname
this.props.params.paramName
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same error except my function was called getSearch().
I found it very strange as everything was according to React docs.
Occurs I just had to change the function name to be named useSearch(), ie `use` prefix.

Answer (score -1):

For react-router-dom 6.x users can simply convert components to functional arrow component:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return ( 
    <div className={location.pathname === 'home' && 'is-home'}>
      <NavLink to="/">Go home</NavLink>
    </div> 
  )
}
export default Navigation
```

Answer (score -2):

For anyone may face this stupid error, i have the same error cause my function component name was "index".
Just changing the name of the component was the solution to me.

Answer (score -2):

Try using functional arrow component, that line worked for me.

Comment: You can add code snippet for better understand